# How can I validate uniqueness of an instance in a collection in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer, django-validation

I have the following models.

```
class ServerGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    factor = models.IntegerField()

class ServerGroupMember(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ("server_group", "position"),
            ("server_group", "server"),
        )

    position = models.IntegerField()
    server_group = models.ForeignKey(
        "ServerGroup", related_name="servers", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    server = models.ForeignKey("Server", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A ServerGroup has a couple of properties, `name` and `factor`, and a collection of `ServerGroupMember` objects.  Each `ServerGroupMember` object, contains an integer `position` and a reference to a `Server` object. For a given `ServerGroup` the `position` must be unique, and for a given `ServerGroup` the `server` must be unique.  However, globally, the position and server objects do not have to be unique, as in 2 ServerGroups may contain a server at postion 1, and the same Server may appear in multiple Server Groups, just not multiple times in the same Server Group.

Given that I have the following serializers, how can I validate the above?  The model currently does validate the condition at the database level, but will raise a unique constraint error if I attempt to violate it.  What I want is to be able to detect this in my views, such that I can return an appropriate validation error message response before it has a chance to hit the DB and raise that exception.

```
class ServerGroupMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ServerGroupMember
        fields = ("position", "server")
    server = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_name="name", queryset=models.Server.objects.all()
    )

class SrvereGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ServerrGroup
        fields = ("name", "factor", "servers")
    servers = ServerGroupMemberSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data): ...
    def update(self, validated_data): ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alwas check your validations when overriding the `clean()` method in your model, or also validating in `serializers.py`. 
Also, the validation only concerns your `not ForeignKey` fields, since you can't add a `ServerGroupMember` member_one twice to a  `ServerGroup` server_test.

```
class ServerGroupMember(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ("server_group", "position"),
            ("server_group", "server"),
        )

    position = models.IntegerField()
    server_group = models.ForeignKey(
        "ServerGroup", related_name="servers", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    server = models.ForeignKey("Server", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def clean(self):
       super().clean()
       if self.position in ServerGroup.server_group_set.all().values_list('position', flat=True):
           raise ValidationError(f"Position {self.position} already exists for ServerGroup {self.server_group.name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to do this, but still curious if this is the best approach here.  This seems to work fine for creating new `ServerGroupMember` instances.  Although not sure if it will work as well for the Update case, that is yet to be tried.

In the views, while instantiating the serializer, I passed to the constructor of the serializer, a context object containing the `ServerGroup` name. E.g.

```
def post(self, request: Request, name: str, format=None) -> Response:
    server_group = self.get_object()  # defined elsewhere
    serializer = serializers.ServerGroupMemberSerializer(
        data=request.data, context={"server_group": server_group.name}
    )
    ...
```

Then in the `ServerGroupMemberSerializer` I added field-level validators, e.g.

```
def validate_position(self, value):
    server_group = self.context.get("server_group")
    try:
        models.ServerGroupMember.objects.get(
            server_group__name=server_group, position=position
        )
    except models.ServerGroupMember.DoesNotExist:
        return value
    raise serializers.ValidationError(
        f"A server group member with position {position} already exists"
    )

def validate_server(self, value):
    ... # Follow same pattern as above
```